# Show message of dialog box via RFC

Tags: abap

I am calling this via RFC:

```
  SUBMIT (IV_REPORT_NAME)
     WITH SELECTION-TABLE selection_table
    AND RETURN.
```

I get an empty result.

If I call this code via se80, then I get this message:

```
Narrow down the selection
```

Is there a way to get this message programmatically?

I would like to return this message in my RFC function module.

Comment: First I would check, if the system variables hold the message right after the SUBMIT (sy-msgid sy-msgnr sy-msgty etc.) If yes, you can read it out and get it back through the RFC FM.

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai I checked these values with the debugger. They are all empty after SUBMIT.

Comment: What kind of report you call? Standard or custom? Tell use the name if it is standard